# Falha ao conectar em SQLSERVER remoto no Ubuntu por certificado ssl auto assinado

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu, ssl, certificado-digital, odbc

Estou recebendo um exceção ao fazer uma chamada do PHP 8.1 instalado em servidor Ubuntu 18.04 a um servidor SQLServer remoto.

Segui o [Tutorial de instalação de Linux e macOS para Drivers da Microsoft para PHP para SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac), para instalação dos drivers do `sqlsrv`, porém são gerados erros na confiabilidade do certificado da conexão do Ubuntu para o SQL Server.

Ao fazer uma chamada, recebo o erro abaixo:

> ```
> SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL  
> Provider: [error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate 
> verify failed:self signed certificate]
> ```

Alguém já enfrentou esse problema ?

Answer (score -1):

Olá! Aqui eu uso o **Laravel**. Para configurar a conexão com o banco de dados o Laravel utiliza o arquivo database.php que fica na pasta **config**. Se for o seu caso, é só você adicionar na conexão **sqlsrv** o atributo **encrypt** que mencionei acima, por exemplo, ficaria assim:

```
'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'database'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'secret'),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'encrypt' => 'no' //Aqui o atributo que mencionei
        ]
```

Caso você não use Laravel, teria que adicionar esse atributo na configuração da sua conexão com o banco de dados.

Abraços!

Comment: Flavio, obrigado! Mas poderia explicar melhor, qual arquivo devo alterar e passar esses parâmetros?

Comment: Opa! Atualizei meu comentário, veja se agora lhe ajuda. Abraços!